# How can I upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 13.04 using minimal cd

Tags: installation, 11.10, dual-boot, upgrade, 13.04

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 from 11.10. I don't have a CPU that supports pae, and from what I uderstood, that means I have to use the minimal cd. I am running a dual boot with windows XP,and I just want to upgrade 11.10 to 13.04 without deleting any of my files or messing up my dual boot situation. Is that possible with the minimal cd? Will it mess up my partitions, can I choose which partition to install it on? Or am I totally confused and am trying to do the impossible :P... If it is possible, can I have a step by step explanation of how to do it?

Thanks,

Hopeless newb

Comment: I don't know about minimal CD, but you can upgrade from the within the terminal in Ubuntu.

Comment: Any reason you cannot use the normal distribution upgrade mechanism inside Ubuntu?  First get to 12.04, that will make things a lot easier.

Comment: @ Frederik Can I upgrade directly to 13.04 through that method?

Comment: no - you cannot skip over releases - you have to go 12.04 - 12.10 - 13.04

Comment: Even if I get the live cd?

Comment: no - you still cannot got straight to 13.04 - it is not supported.

Comment: So I should get 12.04 first?

Comment: just upgrade via update-manager - your non-pae kernel would be kept.

Comment: Is the download smaller than the live cd download?

Comment: it is similar/same